# Android CyanogenMod FM Player app

Tags: android, android-2.2-froyo, cyanogenmod, fm-radio

Hi i am trying to build an FM player for cyanogen mod. I got the code form Cyanogen mod git

https://github.com/CyanogenMod/android_packages_apps_FM

This is for those which use MIUI Rom.

Is there any way for me to compile the code and use it or customize it so as to built my on app. When I import it to eclipse i get error for may imports that are not supported by android stock sdk like many FM libraries. Is it possible for me to run this app some how? In eclipse or some where else how should i proceed. I found on searching that creating an FM player is tough as it need to integrate the libraries for FM chip. Please give your suggestions nothing seems to work for me.

How to use it for android libraries.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To compile most of the apps included in CyanogenMod, you have to check out CM's entire source[1] first, then import the whole thing into an Eclipse project[2] (assuming you're using Eclipse, don't know about other IDEs). This will enable you to build and run any app included in CyanogenMod.

[1] http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Building_from_source
[2] http://wiki.cyanogenmod.com/wiki/Loading_source_in_eclipse